# Modifying field access dynamically

Tags: profile, access

I would like to know whether it is possible modify field access on a record based on criteria like "ownership" etc.

For example, the date of birth field on account should be made accessible only for the account owner and not for anyone else.

Is this possible in Salesforce ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write validation rules, such as:

```
$User.Id != Account.OwnerId && Birthdate != PriorValue(Birthdate)
```

And also by way of triggers.

However, there's no "configuration-only" (e.g. by modifying a layout or profile) way to specify that a field is read-only in the way you've described.