# How to Show a Field Only to the Account Owner - options?

Tags: apex, visualforce

We have a requirement to hide DOB to all users apart from the Account Owner (which gets defaulted with the user who creates that account record).

We will like to preserve the OOTB pagelayout and do not introduce a brand new VF page for Account Layout for this.

I am thinking of the following

a) Remove only the DOB field from the Account Page Layout

b) Add another section below the Account Page Layout containing a embedded VF page  which will display the Account DOB only if the current user is the Account Owner.

c) I believe I will be able to add this logic (*checking logged in user is Current Account's owner*) in the standard controller extension code. I believe adding only the embedded VF only for DOB is far better than introducing a brand new page for the entire display Account Layout.

d) For all other users (non-Account Owners), the embedded visualforce page will display a message like "Sorry you are not authorized to view this"

Is this design feasible or does it have any pitfalls/gotchas that I should be aware of ?

Comment: I don't see a problem with it. Though I would simply not show the DOB instead of the message

Comment: Have you considered the effect this will have on list views, reports, SOQL queries, and integrations? It's one thing to say you'll just remove a field, but in practice, you might make it very hard to do something things like "finding my contacts that have a birthday this month." You might be asking for a lot of work if you don't think this through carefully.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for your inputs. Our legal dept does not want anyone apart from Account Owner to have access to this field. I do not believe this field is used in any of our integrations and our users in general are not aware of how SOQL works. List Views is a good catch. I also believe I need to do some homework to see if there are any reports that has access to this field...Thanks for your inputs :)

Comment: I encourage you to look at Custom Encrypted Fields (https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm&language=en). The security issues are different than what you outlined, but perhaps your Legal Department can use this to find out other acceptable approaches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying field access dynamically](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118455/modifying-field-access-dynamically)